# What's the meaning of the "Stages" on Spark UI for Streaming Scenarios

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm working on Spark Streaming and trying to monitor and improve the performance for the streaming apps. But I'm confusing to the following questions.

1. What's the meaning for each stages on Spark Portal for "Spark Streaming" 
   apps.
2. Not all the "Transformation" mapped to the tasks. And how to target the "Transformation" to the mapped tasks.

**Streaming Code Snapshot**:

```
val transformed = input.flatMap(i => processInput(i))
val aggregated = transformed.reduceByKeyAndWindow(reduce(_, _), Seconds(aggregateWindowSizeInSeconds), Seconds(slidingIntervalInSeconds))
val finalized = aggregated.mapValues(finalize(_))
finalized
```

> (Only the Flatmap stages occurred on the portal.)

**Spark Streaming Portal**
[image: Spark Streaming, Spark Portal]

Thanks,

Tao

Answer (score 1):

Spark takes the individual commands from your source and optimizes then into a plan of tasks to be executed on the cluster. One example of one such optimization is [map-fusion](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Map_(higher-order_function)#/Optimizations): two calls to map come in, one single map task comes out. The **stage** is a higher-level boundary between groups of tasks, defined such that to cross that boundary you have to perform a shuffle.

So:

- each of the operators you call on your RDD result in actions and transformations.
- These result in a DAG of operators.
- The DAG is compiled into stages.
- Each stage is executed as a series of 
  tasks.